# Unable to import pyplot in pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to import pyplot using given command but got error:

```
python -m pip install pyplot
```

> Collecting pyplot
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for pyplot

Validated matplotlib and it is already imported:

```
pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2020.06.20 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\kratica rastogi\pycharmprojects\mlmodelbuilding\venv\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
```

How to install pyplot in pycharm?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Isn't pyplot installed when matplotlib is installed?   Have you tried ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt```?

Comment: is pycharm running on same enviroment where pyplot is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in your code.

```py
# test.py

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def your_function1():
    pass
```

you needn't install pyplot. because pyplot is a part of matplotlib module.

Answer (score 0):

pyplot is part of matplotlib, so when you install matplotlib with `pip install matplotlib`, all you have to do is import pyplot in your python file.

```
# example.py

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```